# Updated AutoMapper and now receiving unmapped property exception

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Playlist, PlaylistDto>()
      .ReverseMap()
      .ForMember(playlist => playlist.Folder,
          opt => opt.MapFrom(playlistDto => folderDao.Get(playlistDto.FolderId)));
```

Which converts a Playlist object to a PlaylistDto object and back. It seemed to work great before I updated AutoMapper.

Now, when I call:

```
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

I see:

```
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
=====================================================
PlaylistDto -> Playlist (Source member list)
Streamus.Dto.PlaylistDto -> Streamus.Domain.Playlist (Source member list)
-----------------------------------------------------
FolderId
```

Playlist and PlaylistDto look like:

```
[DataContract]
public class PlaylistDto
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "folderId")]
    public Guid FolderId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "items")]
    public List<PlaylistItemDto> Items { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "sequence")]
    public int Sequence { get; set; }

    public PlaylistDto()
    {
        Id = Guid.Empty;
        Title = string.Empty;
        Items = new List<PlaylistItemDto>();
    }

    public static PlaylistDto Create(Playlist playlist)
    {
        PlaylistDto playlistDto = Mapper.Map<Playlist, PlaylistDto>(playlist);
        return playlistDto;
    }
}

public class Playlist : AbstractShareableDomainEntity
{
    public virtual Folder Folder { get; set; }
    //  Use interfaces so NHibernate can inject with its own collection implementation.
    public virtual ICollection<PlaylistItem> Items { get; set; }
    public virtual int Sequence { get; set; }

    public Playlist()
    {
        Id = Guid.Empty;
        Title = string.Empty;
        Items = new List<PlaylistItem>();
        Sequence = -1;
    }
}
```

Why is AutoMapper unable to automatically derive the FolderId from Folder after updating?

Note that it still complains even if I try to explicitly define the mapping to FolderId:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Playlist, PlaylistDto>()
       .ForMember(playlist => playlist.FolderId,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(playlistDto => playlistDto.Folder.Id))
      .ReverseMap()
      .ForMember(playlist => playlist.Folder,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(playlistDto => folderDao.Get(playlistDto.FolderId)));
```

Comment: When you explicitly map the `FolderId`.. is the error exactly the same?

Comment: Yes, I receive the same error when I explicitly map it. Weird, right?

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET application? I assume you're initializing AutoMapper in your Application_Start/Global.asax yes? Have you tried completely restarting the local web server/closing Visual Studio and re-opening?

Comment: I'll restart the VM. One sec. :)

Comment: Restarting the VM and doing a full clean and rebuild did not resolve the issue. Maybe I just need to roll back AutoMapper..

Comment: Very strange indeed. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Oh I figured it out. I can't use the ReverseMap anymore like that. If I declare both explicitly instead of ReverseMapping then it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to explicitly declare my mappings:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Playlist, PlaylistDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<PlaylistDto, Playlist>()
    .ForMember(playlist => playlist.Folder,opt => opt.MapFrom(playlistDto => folderDao.Get(playlistDto.FolderId)));
```